# VB chart with asymptote

Tags: vb.net, charts

I have created a functioning cosine and sine graph so far but tan doesn't work as it relies on asymptotes in which I'm not too sure how to get to work with a chart using VB as the graph outputs each point as being connected as one line rather than having separate lines. If anyone has any experience with this I'd be grateful as i can't find anything online that will help me further.

```
  For x As Integer = n To v Step 1
            Dim y As Single
            y = Math.Tan(x / 57.3)
            '57.3 is an approximation for pi/180
            Chart1.Series("plot4").Points.AddXY(x, y)
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to tell us what goes wrong?

Comment: @AndrewMorton sorry if i didn't specify well enough. the lines should be split up by asymptotes but this doesn't happen as the line is continuous

Comment: It looks like you can use the [`IsEmpty`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.datapoint.isempty?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_DataVisualization_Charting_DataPoint_IsEmpty) property of a datapoint. So, detect a discontinuity and add a datapoint maybe half way between the points where you detected it with something like `Chart1.Series("plot4").Points.Add(New DataPoint(halfWay, 0) With {.IsEmpty = True})`. (Credit to Tyler Durden for [this answer to c# chart non continuous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22593401/1115360).)

Comment: @AndrewMorton I've still been a little lost in the woods with how to incorporate the (x,y) into this line of code recently. Any idea how to sub that into the line of code?

Answer (score 0):

If you can detect a discontinuity, then you can add a datapoint with the [.IsEmpty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.datapoint.isempty) property set to True. That point will not be drawn, giving a break in the graph:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting

Public Class Form1

    Sub DrawGraph()

        Chart1.Series.Clear()

        Dim pts As New Series("tan") With {.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line}

        Dim nPoints = 541
        Dim xMin = 0.0
        Dim xMax = Math.PI * 3
        Dim xInc = (xMax - xMin) / nPoints

        For i = 0 To nPoints - 1
            Dim x = xMin + i * xInc
            Dim y = Math.Tan(x)
            If i > 0 Then
                ' Check if the sign of y has changed and its value is large enough to suggest a discontinuity
                If Math.Sign(pts.Points(i - 1).YValues(0)) = -Math.Sign(y) AndAlso Math.Abs(y) > 10 Then
                    pts.Points.Add(New DataPoint(x - xInc / 2, 0) With {.IsEmpty = True})
                End If
            End If

            pts.Points.AddXY(x, y)

        Next

        Chart1.Series.Add(pts)
        Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Minimum = -50
        Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Maximum = 50

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        DrawGraph()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Giving something like this:

[image]

(Please excuse the crudity of this chart. I didn't have time to scale it nicely or colour it.)

---

Ref for inspiration: [c# chart non continuous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22593401/1115360).